# How to convert mcrypt_decrypt to openssl_decrypt in PHP?

Tags: php, openssl, mcrypt

I was handed this code snippet as an example, and I'm trying to make it a little more "modern":

```
$key='09KzF2qMBy58ZWg137N$I4h6UwJvp!ij';
$encrypted='Chttex_vuYYEK-oKQfwYrVCZYbnNh3tMgwGuK-VOsvt7TjF5M6MIcsE6e8DynZrHuxrmtmIpiN215WygdO-hzXnmx45RXzBWdxk_MkIvNoI=';
$encrypted = urlsafe_b64decode($encrypted);
$decrypted = decrypt($encrypted, $key);
$inflated = gzinflate($decrypted);

echo 'Decrypted: '.$inflated."<br />";

function urlsafe_b64decode($data) {
  return base64_decode(str_pad(strtr($data, '-_', '+/'), strlen($data) % 4, '=', STR_PAD_RIGHT));
}

function decrypt($data, $key)
{
    return mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
}
```

I'm on PHP7 and trying to convert this use openssl.  I take the string and run it through the existing 'urlsafe_b64decode' function, then created another 'decrypt' function:

```
function decrypt($string, $key)
{
    return openssl_decrypt($string, 'AES-256-ECB', $key);
}
```

I thought it would be a fairly simply 1-to-1 conversion, but its always returning "false". Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

**edit** : 
Since the service I'm using is a .NET shop, here's their example for .NET for encrypting, if it helps at all.

```
Public Shared Function Encrypt(ByVal data As Byte()) As Byte()
        Dim encrypted As Byte()

        Using rijAlg = New System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged()
            rijAlg.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("encryptionkeyhere")
            rijAlg.Padding = System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode.None
            rijAlg.Mode = System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode.ECB
            Dim encryptor = rijAlg.CreateEncryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV)

            Using msEncrypt = New MemoryStream()
                Using csEncrypt = New System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                    csEncrypt.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
                End Using

                encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray()
            End Using
        End Using

        Return encrypted
End Function
```

**update 2**
So I updated my local server to have mcrypt, and was able to decode the encrypted string from my initial code snippet.  This is the desired response: "sessionid=7bf727043d85e6963e640fb541d886a7454f8091&requestid=1488925528"

After googleing and stackoverflow-ing and experimenting, I'm still unable to decrypt the string correctly using openssl. Is it even possible?

Comment: Why not simply decode your your string with Mcrypt and then re-encrypt it with OpenSSL?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a PHP7 server and I don't have access to install the mcrypt extension, or change the ini file.

Comment: Do not use ECB mode, it is insecure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.

Instead use CBC mode with a random IV, just prefix the encrypted data with the IV for use in decryption, it does not need to be secret.

Comment: The docs for the service I'm trying to use say "Decrypt the string using AES256-ECB".  Are the modes interchangeable? If they `encrypt` using ECB, can I `decrypt` using CBC?

Comment: You may find you cannot decrypt with OpenSSL because of your `$key`. I beleive your key should be hexadecimal.  I found that values generated with Mcrypt using an invalid key cannot be decrypted with OpenSSL. But if use a valid key with Mcrypt, then OpenSSL can decrypt it.

Comment: The "duplicate" answer referred to is advice and not really an answer. This question is about MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 which *can* be decrypted with openssl.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer, but since I'm including a chunk of code, I'm putting it here. It's also lifted from a different site, but I closed the window while i was testing it by accident and can't give proper credit.

It also uses a different cipher method (ECB). But m**aybe it's a starting point for you**. As you'll see, running this code will throw some errors, but in the vardump at the bottom, it does indeed return the encrypted text string.

Hope it helps you! I have to run out the door!

```
<?php

$key = "1234541413411111";
$data = "hello world";

$cipher = mcrypt_encrypt(
    MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
    $key,
    $data,
    MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);

$plain = openssl_decrypt(
    $cipher,
    'aes-128-ecb',
    $key,
    OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_NO_PADDING
);

//try to detect null padding
if (mb_strlen($iv, '8bit') % mb_strlen($plain, '8bit') == 0) {
    preg_match_all('#([\0]+)$#', $plain, $matches);
    if (mb_strlen($matches[1][0], '8bit') > 1) {
        $plain = rtrim($plain, "\0");
        trigger_error('Detected and stripped null padding. Please double-check results!');
    }
}

var_dump(
    $message,
    bin2hex($cipher),
    $plain,
    mb_strlen($message, '8bit'),
    mb_strlen($plain, '8bit'),
    $message === $plain
);
```